# Getting onto the Kungsleden at Hemavan

Tags: public-transport, sweden, hiking

Looking for some advice on the easiest way to get to Hemavan from Stockholm using public transport. I plan on walking South to North along the Kings trail. Aiming to start my walk in late June.

Comment: Google Maps shows various public transit options.

Comment: An other general site is Rome2Rio, for general information and follow up with researching the transport options that site shows

Answer (score 4):

Train and bus is an excellent way to get from Stockholm to Hemavan.
In Sweden, I recommend using [Resrobot](https://reseplanerare.resrobot.se/index.html#!P%7CTP!histId%7C0!histKey%7CH798923), [SJ](https://www.sj.se/), or [Vy](https://www.vy.se/) for public transport planning.  Google Maps sometimes suggests alternatives with transfers that are too short and your connection won't be guaranteed.  SJ can sell tickets that include both train and bus travel.  If you buy a through-ticket from Stockholm to Hemavan, any connections between trains and buses will be guaranteed.

However, timetables for late June are not yet confirmed and tickets typically do not go on sale until around 90 days prior to departure.  You probably won't find any connections if you search now, but try again late March or early April.